# Create DropDownList in UltraGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm trying to create a drop down list with Infragistics WinForms 2015.
I have read a lot of topics online but I could not find what I'm looking for or it did not work.

I did this but it does not work :

```
    private void FrmCVault_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var test = new UltraDropDown();

        test.DataSource = new[] { "A1", "A2", "A3", "Pouet" };

        CVaultGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].ValueList = test;

        CVaultDataSource.Rows.Add(new[] { "A1" });
        CVaultDataSource.Rows.Add(new[] { "A2" });
        CVaultDataSource.Rows.Add(new[] { "A3" });
    }
```

It gives me this :

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like the goal is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` or whatever the equivalent is in `infragistics`.

Comment: @Steve I'd like to have a drop down list. Actually the values A1, A2, A3 are on 3 different rows. I'd like for instance having A2 and A3 in the A1 cell. And select the value that I want by clicking on a drop down list in A1 cell.

Comment: Probably you haven't set the grid cell in edit mode, see CellActivation, CellClickAction and AllowUpdate

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a stand-alone combo box you may use Infragistics UltraCombo. Check the documentation [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo.html) to find out how to use it.
If what you try is to embed drop down in other controls [here](http://blogs.infragistics.com/winforms/wiki/best-practices-for-placing-a-dropdown-or-combo-in-an-wingrid-cell/5.aspx) is nice article how to do this with Infragistics controls

Comment: Actually I just managed to make it. But I really do not know how. I ran the project 2 times, the first one did not work and the second one did...
I do not even know what I've changed Haha
Anyways, I'll take a look to find it out ! Thanks for the documentation btw :)